# Speed Up UPDATE Performance MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, domo

I'm fairly new to SQL, so struggling with the guidance given elsewhere on this.

- I have a table with 1.7M rows and 85 columns
- The column 'Sample ID' gives an identifier for each entry
- The data updates periodically and duplicate Sample IDs are generated with a separate field changing (this is required as part of the dataflow)
- However, the Unit Number will not carry across to the new entry on the Sample ID as this is part of a calculation done based on the field that changes
- Therefore, I want to use the Unit Number from the Sample ID where this is populated to fill the  place where it is NULL

For example:

| Sample ID | Unit Number | +83 other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001A | NULL |  |
| 00001A | 123_abc |  |

to

| Sample ID | Unit Number | +83 other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001A | 123_abc |  |
| 00001A | 123_abc |  |

I have managed to run this successfully using the following code on a small table to test:

```
UPDATE data_tabel as dt1, data_tabel as dt2 
SET dt1.Unit Number = dt2.Unit Number 
WHERE dt1.Sample ID = dt2.Sample ID AND dt1.Unit Number is NULL AND dt2.Unit Number != ''
```

And also successfully with:

```
UPDATE data_tabel as t1 
    INNER JOIN data_tabel as t2 ON 
        t1.Sample ID = t2.Sample ID AND 
        t2.Unit Number IS NOT NULL 
SET t1.Unit Number = t2.Unit Number;
```

However, when running this on my full data table, the speed is incredibly slow (1.5h so far and counting).

Any advice on how to improve the performance of this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows in the update set?  I am thinking of keeping it separate, _then_ folding the data in--including the UnitNumber.

Comment: What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; you can leave out most of the 83 other columns, but do include all indexes and the columns that are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

The main factors that lowerest performance during the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` process in DB are indexes, triggers, constraints and foreign keys. For best performance, you must disable all this during the `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. For example:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE table_name disable KEYS;

-- update table_name
 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
ALTER TABLE table_name enable KEYS;
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in your SECOND attempt, and hopefully only a bad paste of your code, you are updating EVERY record as you dont have the

```
WHERE t1.UnitNumber IS NULL
```

Sometimes trying to mask your database and query is not worth it, even if somewhat proprietary system.  queries in general when stripped to basics should not pose a risk.  Also, bad to have spaces within column names such as your Unit Number, but also think this is just for your masking query sample.

You may need to look at your data... What is it you want.  The FIRST entry that has a non-null value for a given SampleID, or the most recent to be carried down to all other entries?  Do you have a master parent table that this SampleID comes from? and if so, maybe this latest computed status should be on that parent record instead of duplicated to every detail row by same context.

Might be better to assess your database design implementation than back-patching the data.